# how to remove a big file from gitlab storage completely

Tags: git, gitlab

I had a `project.rar` file that was 350 MB. unfortunately I commit it and push it to remote gitlab.

now the gitlab storage is 500 MB. how to remove that file from gitlab storage ?

I tried these :

```
 git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch project.rar" HEAD
```

and then `git push --all` but not work.

please help,
thanks

Comment: Did some search, and people are talking about using [BFG repo cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) for this. You may want to check that out.

Comment: As Gitlab uses some internal refs to track commits and merge requests, even if you remove them from the `refs/heads/*` branches, `refs/tags/*` tags and merge requests refs, and they become invisible to client users, they could still be kept in Gitlab repository.  You may ask Gitlab administrators for help.

Answer (score 2):

You *must* follow [GitLab's guide to purge files from a repository](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/reducing_the_repo_size_using_git.html#purge-files-from-repository-history) to actually reduce the repository size.

You must export your project, run `git filter-repo`, then upload the resulting filter file to [GitLab's repository cleanup](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/reducing_the_repo_size_using_git.html#repository-cleanup).