# How to reduce git repository storage after migrating git repository to git lfs?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-lfs

I've created a test repository on GitLab and pushed a .mp4 (500MB) file to that repository. After that, I tried to migrate this repository to Git LFS and run the force push command. But when I check the usage quotas on Gitlab, both "LFS storage" and "Repository" have 500MB usage, so the total usage of project is 1GB.
[image: Gitlab usage quotas]

Why after migrating success, the "Repository" usage is not reduced?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to remove a big file from gitlab storage completely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73398968/how-to-remove-a-big-file-from-gitlab-storage-completely)

Answer (score 0):

When you migrate a repository to LFS, the result is:

- a *new repository* that is small, and
- the large files, stored (or to be stored) on the large file server.

The *old* repository is still large and if you add the *new* repository's commits to the *old* repository, it will continue to be large.  The only thing to do with the old repository is to archive it and remove it from active service.  Call the new repository something else, to avoid the usual silly human mistakes people will make if you don't do that.